# Does the Spyder IDE include a GUI builder like GUIDE from MATLAB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, spyder

I'm transitioning from MATLAB to Python and I found that the Spyder IDE is the closest environment I found that resembles MATLAB.  Does the Spyder IDE include a GUI builder like GUIDE from MATLAB? If not, is there a way to incorporate a GUI environment to Spyder?

Comment: For GUI you should use modules such as tkinter, kivy, Qt, or many other ones which depends on your need. Unlike Matlab, Spyder is just an IDE and does not provide any GUI builder.

Comment: You can use PyQt to build GUIs for Python. Although it's not directly integrated in Spyder, you can use Qt Designer, which is a standalone software to build GUIs very similar to GUIDE. For example, check this [blog post](http://pythonforengineers.com/your-first-gui-app-with-python-and-pyqt/) for a simple app built using PyQt.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for the GUI to be integrated it sucks when you have to use a separate program just for the GUI.

Comment: IMO, an IDE is where you *develop*, not *design*. In other words, your business logic is written by the IDE and exposed to a GUI via some type of external module

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no such facility in Spyder and we don't have plans to add it in the future, sorry.